# The constructor CursorAdapter(Context, Cursor, int) is undefined..?

Tags: android

Please help me with this error

```
public class CustomAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

public CustomAdapter(Context context,Cursor c,int flags) {
    **super(context,c,flags);** EEROR ON THIS LINE

}

Thread thread = new Thread() {

        public void run() {

            customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(MyActivity.this, databaseHelper.getAllData(), CursorAdapter.NO_SELECTION);

            listView.setAdapter(customAdapter);
        }
```

The log:

```
10-23 12:37:14.617: E/AndroidRuntime(668): java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
10-23 12:37:14.617: E/AndroidRuntime(668):  at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:121)
10-23 12:37:14.617: E/AndroidRuntime(668):  at android.widget.CursorAdapter$ChangeObserver.<init>(CursorAdapter.java:449)
10-23 12:37:14.617: E/AndroidRuntime(668):  at android.widget.CursorAdapter.init(CursorAdapter.java:170)
10-23 12:37:14.617: E/AndroidRuntime(668):  at android.widget.CursorAdapter.<init>(CursorAdapter.java:116)
10-23 12:37:14.617: E/AndroidRuntime(668):  at com.example.databasesim.CustomAdapter.<init>(CustomAdapter.java:18)
10-23 12:37:14.617: E/AndroidRuntime(668):  at com.example.databasesim.MyActivity$1.run(MyActivity.java:39)
```

Comment: you claim to have a compile time error but it is a Runtime error

Comment: yes it is a run time error.can you let me know where i am wrong

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are making a UI action inside a non ui thread..

you should remove this code from the thread, and do it in the main thread, or use `runOnUiThread(action)` check http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable)

Comment: these are two different classes...Starting from new thread is a different class.Error is on line super(context,c,flags); and customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(MyActivity.this, databaseHelper.getAllData(), CursorAdapter.NO_SELECTION);

Comment: private CustomAdapter customAdapter; Thread thread = new Thread() {

   public void run() {

    customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(MyActivity.this,
      databaseHelper.getAllData(), CursorAdapter.NO_SELECTION);

    listView.setAdapter(customAdapter);
   }
I have alredy initialized that...

Comment: i mean move the (`customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(MyActivity.this, databaseHelper.getAllData(), CursorAdapter.NO_SELECTION);`) in the `onCreate` method like Andy's..

Answer (score 0):

Try to create your adapter in UI thread:

```
puvblic class MyActivity extends Activity {

    public void onCreate(...) {
       customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(MyActivity.this, databaseHelper.getAllData(), CursorAdapter.NO_SELECTION);
    }
}
```

Comment: no you don't. You should move that creation of your adapter out of the new Thread {...} section